# Error al enviar la solicitud PHP, C#

Tags: php, c#, codeigniter

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en C# que se conecta a un servicio web pero cuando intento enviar los datos via POST me sale un error en mi aplicación en C#:

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Error al enviar la solicitud.
>   ---> System.Net.WebException: Se ha terminado la conexión: Error inesperado de envío.   ---> System.IO.IOException: No se puede escribir
>   datos de la conexión de transporte: Se ha forzado la interrupción de
>   una conexión existente por el host remoto. --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Se ha forzado la interrupción de
>   una conexión existente por el host remoto

**Pero hay algo aún más importante cuando envío los datos via Postman en RAW los datos se envían correctamente.**

Aquí le envío los datos al servicio

```
 //crear la Instacia del Api
            ApiServices api = new ApiServices();


            //Envia las Modalidades
            var Modali = manager.Getdata("Select * , descrip as Modalidad from modalidades with(nolock) ");
            if (Modali.Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                //Inserta los Clientes en el Servidor
                var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Modali);
                var data1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Modalidades>>(data);
                var serial = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data1);
                await api.Post(serial, "", "Cuentasporcobrar/EnviarModalidades/590025");
                               EscribirLinea("Insertó los Datos de la modalidades en el Servidor");

            }
```

este es el código que envía la petición POST

```
    public async Task<bool> Post(string Data, string token, string Controler)
    {
        try
        {

            var Cliente = new HttpClient
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri(configuracion.ServicioRest )
            };

            Cliente.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            Cliente.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            StringContent content = new StringContent(Data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var Url = string.Format("{0}", Controler);
            var Respuesta = await Cliente.PostAsync(Url, content);

            if (!Respuesta.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }

        return false;
    }
```

**NOTA:** Esto funciona correctamente cuando utilizo mi servidor local Xamp

Comment: Mencionas que en el local si funciona.. seguro que en otro servidor está actualizado ése servicio?

Comment: entiendo que si porque en embos utilizo php version 5.6 en la local funciona bien en el servidor me da un error.

Answer (score -1):

Necesitas agregar el protocolo de seguridad:

```csharp
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Saludos

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).